# Unable to insert data from html table into MySql db

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I am trying to build a sales order form for an inventory management program I am building for a friend.  I have created a html table which loads each row from a drop down element using ajax, filling the remaining cells from the MySQL database. The user can add rows and insert more products into the list.  There is logic to serialize each row element(e.g. name_1, age_1, email_1, name_2, age_2,email_2 etc.)

I used a tutorial that I found and reworked it to fit my database table (that is why the names appear off)

Now my challenge is to take the data from the html table (which I wrapped with a form tag) and insert the data into another table in my database.  I have not been able to get the $_POST data to appear in my target page (addDetails.php)

I have tried a simple statement to expose the $_POST values but I am getting nothing.  I am using ajax to retrieve the fields from MySQL and then javascript to insert them into the html table.

This is my validation statement:

```
if ($_POST)
{
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";
}
?>
```

I am new to using ajax and the multiple row html data input is not something I am finding much information about.  I am open to suggestions.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>How to autocomplete data on multiple fields with jQuery and AJAX</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link href='jquery-ui.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' >
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('keydown', '.username', function() {
                
                var id = this.id;
                var splitid = id.split('_');
                var index = splitid[1];

                $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "getDetails.php",
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                search: request.term,request:1
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                response( data );
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                        var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                        // AJAX
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'getDetails.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {userid:userid,request:2},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success:function(response){
                                
                                var len = response.length;

                                if(len > 0){
                                    var id = response[0]['id'];
                                    var name = response[0]['name'];
                                    var email = response[0]['email'];
                                    var age = response[0]['age'];
                                    var salary = response[0]['salary'];

                                    document.getElementById('name_'+index).value = name;
                                    document.getElementById('age_'+index).value = age;
                                    document.getElementById('email_'+index).value = email;
                                    document.getElementById('salary_'+index).value = salary;
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }
                        });

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
            
            // Add more
            $('#addmore').click(function(){

                // Get last id 
                var lastname_id = $('.tr_input input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').last().attr('id');
                var split_id = lastname_id.split('_');

                // New index
                var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

                // Create row with input elements
                var html = "<tr class='tr_input'><td><input type='text' size='65' class='username' id='username_"+index+"' placeholder='Enter Next Crop'></td><td><input type='text' size='8' class='name' id='name_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' size='8' class='email' id='email_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' size='8' class='salary' id='salary_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' size='8' class='age' id='age_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' size='8' class='qty' id='qty_"+index+"' ></td></tr>";

                // Append data
                $('tbody').append(html);
                
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
    <h3><span>Add Items to the Invoice</span></h3>  <br>  
    <form method="POST" action="addDetails.php">
        <table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Crop Name</th>
                <th>Crop ID</th>
                <th>Product #</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Available</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class='tr_input'>
                <td><input type='text' size = '65' class='username' id='username_1' placeholder='Enter Crop Name'></td>
                <td><input type='text' size = '8' class='name' id='name_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' size = '8' class='email' id='email_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' size = '8' class='salary' id='salary_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' size = '8' class='age' id='age_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' size = '8' class='qty' id='qty_1'></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <br>
        <input type='button' value='Add more' id='addmore'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='sbmt'>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my add Detail.php page

```
<?php
if ($_POST)
{
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";
}
?>


<?php
    if("" == trim($_POST['userName'])){
     $username = 'Anonymous';
 } 

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $id = $_POST['username'];
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $salary = $_POST['salary'];
     $age = $_POST['age'];
     $qty = $_POST['qty'];


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <h2>Test of passing data</h2>
            <p>Username = <?php echo $username; ?></p>
            <p>Id = <?php echo $id; ?></p>
            <p>Name = <?php echo $name; ?></p>
            <p>Email = <?php echo $email; ?></p>
            <p>Salary = <?php echo $salary; ?></p>
            <p>Age = <?php echo $age; ?></p>
            <p>Qty = <?php echo $qty; ?></p>
        </body>

    </head>

</html>
```

Comment: Check out chrome's dev tools -> network tab, filter on XHR and see if the POST is being made and what it contains. In addition, look at the console tab and see if  you have javascript errors that are preventing the post from firing.

Comment: on this if ($_POST)
{
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";
}
?>  try $_REQUEST insted of $_POST and let me know.

Comment: I checked dev tools, there are no POSTs being made in XHR, but no error in console either.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: I also checked the target page and changed $_POST to $_REQUEST but nothing changed.  NO errors are showing. and my html text appears.  I am trying to set the $_POST values to a variable then echo out the variable.

Comment: I did finally figure out the issue with my $_POST.  I was using id as the identifier in the input element (id="name_1"), when I added name to the input element (e.g. name="name_1") the data was posted correctly.